# How to run an android project with project build target 4.1 on a 2.3 AVD in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a project with project `build target 4.1`, when I try to run that in Eclipse with "Run as -> Run configurations", in Target `AVD` list box, only `4.1 AVD` are listed, I can only run on `4.1 AVDs`.

I tried to set the project build target as `2.3`, the `2.3 AVD` are listed in target list box, 
but problem is, this will cause compile error, for example, if I use following code:

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
```

Using build target as 2.3 will cause error, seems I have to use a higher build target like 4.1 to compile the projects.

I think one workaround is to export the project as apk, then use abd to install and debug on 2.3 AVD.

the uses-sdk is as following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

my question is, how to run an android project with project build target 4.1 on a 2.3 AVD in Eclipse, as in the "Run as -> Run configurations" dialog, 2.3 AVD can not be listed, how can I choose a 2.3 target to run project?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: there shouldn't be a problem running it, unless you use API's which are not available in GB, e.g. ABS

Comment: There is no problem with running a "project build target 4.1 on a 2.3 AVD in Eclipse". The problem perhaps lies elsewhere within your project, such as your `<uses-sdk>` element. Please post your manifest, or at least the `<uses-sdk>` element, in an edit to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edit the question, my question is if project build target is 4.1, in "Run as -> Run configurations" dialog, 2.3 AVD can not be listed, how can I choose a 2.3 target to run project?

Answer (score 0):

**Run as -> Run configurations -> Always prompt to pick device**

By doing this, whenever you run your application, a dialog would appear from where you *should* be able to choose your Android 2.3 device.

Comment: I am glad that it works for you now! Please feel free to  upvote/accept my answer as the solution. :)